# IntelliJ not seeing my Android device

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ for my Android development and for some reason it is not seeing my actual android device. It *does* see my emulator, so I am able to do everything in IntelliJ on the emulator.

However when I want to deploy to my actual phone device it does not appear in the IntelliJ device list, and so I need to use Eclipse.

Any idea when Idea does not see my device?

Comment: Do you see your device in `adb devices` output?

Comment: Yes, and I see it in Eclipse. Just not in IntelliJ

Comment: Try to specify that you want the app to run on USB Device in the Run/Debug configuration dialog: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2752840/screens/snap1120-1331939521.png. This works fine in IDEA 11.0.2 and 11.1 EAP.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Android Run/Debug configuration](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-android-application.html) has an option to run the app on the **USB Device**.

Answer (score 1):

I just answered a copy of this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17792556/1048563

The answer is also included in this blog post: http://vuknikolic.me/2013/03/10/idea-intellij-usb-device-not-found-android-problem/