# Intellij Idea does not find my android device

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea, adb

Hi I want to do some test app that uses sound recording, but it doesn't work in the emulator. I need to test it on my phone but every time I change the option to use USB, it never detects my Wildfire S ... which is connected and in USB debugging mode.

It says "No USB Device Found".

Using 11.1.2

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you look at this link in Android documentation? http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html It helped me while using my Samsung to test applications.

Comment: Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem was solved by installing HTC Sync it installed the correct driver and allowed me to detect the device.

Answer (score 13):

This works for me:

1. Unblock developers settings in your phone ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18103158/2275775))
2. Ensure your Adb USB driver is installed (Windows 8 and 8.1 solution):

   - Connect your device via usb
   - Right Click on 'This PC' (My Computer) -> Manage -> Device Manager -> Other devices
   - If usb driver is not installed, in 'Other dvices' will appear your phone
   - Download ADP USB driver for your phone ([common drivers list](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers))
   - Right click on your device -> Update Driver Software -> Browse your computer for downloaded driver directory
   - Click Next and install drivers.
   - You can receive error like this:

     > A problem was encountered while attempting to add the driver to the store.
   - Handle error with [unblocking unsigned drivers installation](http://revryl.com/2013/08/06/install-unsigned-drivers/)
3. IDE is still not recognize your phone

   - try run command ([set PATH if command is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564514/adb-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or) )  : 

     `adb devices`
   - with result like this:

     > adb server is out of date.  killing...
     >   daemon started successfully  `
   - IDE should now recognize your device

Answer (score 6):

I came across this problem today and was getting increasingly frustrated until I found this blog post: http://vuknikolic.me/2013/03/10/idea-intellij-usb-device-not-found-android-problem/

Basically, you want to run two commands:

```
adb kill-server
adb devices
```

When you run the second command, it will restart the server and you should see your device listed:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
37329B0B96FD00EC    device
```

If you try running the application again from IntelliJ (or Android Studio), it should work if your device was listed above.

Comment: If even after running these two commands list of devices is shown blank, make sure to enable usb debugging in your phone. For realme phone this was another step.

Answer (score 4):

It could be the configuration of your phone. Open the developer settings and make sure that the option of USB Configuration is in:

> MIDI

Answer (score 1):

for Sony EXPERIA I installed PC Companion and then everything was ok.
(or you can just install or update your device deriver but it didn't work for me on windows 7.)

PC Companion Download link: http://www.sonymobile.com/gb/tools/pc-companion/

Answer (score 1):

[Android sdk Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVxXX.jpg)

You can install or update your Google Usb Driver in sdk manager. It may help for any unrecognized  device. Click upper link to see where.

Answer (score 0):

everyone, 
  Please upgrade to the new version (for me it's 12.04). 
  Everything is ok now!

Don't waste more time in the forking bugs and version cross.

Comment: I use the new version of Android but the idea version is 11.xx

Comment: I use the new version of Android but the idea version is 11.xx. 
I found that every new updated version of idea will meet the new version of some standards such as maven, android, spring framework and so on.

If I can understand all it's better well upgrade to new version is a  
simple and straight answer.

Answer (score 0):

Connect Your Phone To ADB : Linux

1. Create a file called android.rules
2. Without switching directories, run the following commands :
    a.   sudo cp android.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
    b.   sudo chmod 644   /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
    c.   sudo chown root. /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
    d.   sudo service udev restart
    e.   sudo your-path-to-adb-executable/adb kill-server
    f.   sudo your-path-to-adb-executable/adb start-server
    g.   your-path-to-adb-executable/adb devices
3. Will be able to see on Android Studio

[Credits: [set up device for development (?????? no permissions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210152/set-up-device-for-development-no-permissions])

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that the USB cable was not supporting data transfer, due to which the device was not listed using `adb devices`. I was able to see the device after trying with a different USB cable that supported data transfer.